# Is <Struct at NULL> the same as "Struct is null"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio, BuildVision gives me an Error, from which the Message is < Struct **at** Null>

Is it the same as "Struct is Null", or is it something different?

I'm asking because I couldn't find anything on the web with this message. All that I could find was pointing to "Struct is Null", but all I found didn't help me out! I was wondering if this is because of the **at**?

Edit:

I add a screenie of the debugger window with the < Struct at Null>-Stuff.  I have a second question as well: I want to catch this exception with an if-else clause. How can I say

```
if(value == <struct at NULL>)
    this()
else
    that()
```

This is not working, although the debugger says the value would be .

[image]

In This example I try to check if components of the "distribution" are null to determine the state of the Distribution object. Here is the origianl code:

```
if (Distribution.distBrowserName() == NULL || Distribution.getShape() == NULL)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
```

Comment: What is the error code?

Comment: sorry, but i dont believe you that "< Struct at Null>" is the full error message

Comment: Post some code? *at* suggests you are mucking about with pointers. And maybe pointers to pointers

Comment: I am trying to call something in the form `strategy->plot()`, while strategy being a custom class pointer. THe Error message occuring is in an "Acces rading Violation..." Window. The Error in the BuildVision is just <Struct at NULL>

Comment: And is `strategy` NULL? Where does it get initialised?

Comment: I think you need to edit the question to have a minimal, verifiable example

Comment: The code snippet that you have posted is invalid, but you haven't posted the code that's actually creating the error.

Comment: Have you verified that `Distribution` isn't null?

Comment: Distribution is <struct at NULL > whatever that means

Comment: It is not a common diagnostic.  My psychic debugger says that Distribution is a object& reference.  References are pointers under the hood and should always be initialized.  But with sufficient UB that can go wrong, a corrupted pointer will always make the program blow up with an access violation.  If you are sure that it is initialized correctly and cannot dangle then set a data breakpoint to trap it getting modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also encountered this problem recently. In my case, it was caused by a reference that had been initialized by dereferencing a null pointer. Basically, it was something like this:

```
Foo * fooPtr = nullptr;
// ...
Foo & fooRef = *fooPtr;
// ...
fooRef.Bar() // read access violation
```

Even if the exception is thrown at the third line, the problem actually lies in the second line because dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior. Here, it creates a reference to an invalid object which the Visual Studio debugger represents as `<Struct at NULL>`. Trying to access a member of this invalid object then results in a read access violation.

If you still want to verify whether a reference is `<Struct at NULL>`, you can do it by comparing its address with null:

```
if (&fooRef != nullptr)
{
    fooRef.Bar();
}
```

Here are some other interesting questions regarding invalid references:

[Is null reference possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364536/is-null-reference-possible)

[Why don't I need to check if references are invalid/null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524870/why-dont-i-need-to-check-if-references-are-invalid-null)

Answer (score 3):

(Three months late, but this is the top search result for me.  Hope I can help someone.)

To answer your first question:  Yes, `<struct at NULL>` means that the reference to the object (struct or class) is null.  This message can appear with a dangling reference, as appears to be your case.  It can also appear with a dangling/null pointer.

So, to your second question, it's the reference to the `Distribution` object itself in your example that's causing the problem, so you're probably looking for a dangling reference somewhere.

A useful feature in MSVS that people often overlook is Data Breakpoints.  If you're unfamiliar with them, you can [read about them here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx#Anchor_4).  In this case, for instance, it could help you track down whether your `Distribution` variable is being affected someplace you didn't expect.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I am so sorry, I just forgot to like and accept this answer ^^. Hope you're still active and this message reaches you =)

Comment: @monamona No worries! :)